# MYSQL Query for Grouping Column Based on Different Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have project table in following format:

[image]

And, I need to have MYSQL that can give me data in following format:

[image]

Basically, I have to group the data based on location. Then have to count the successful and unsuccessful projects. "Successful" column has total count of projects for which percentageRaised is more than or equal to 1 and Unsuccessful column has total count of project for which percetageRaised in less than 1.

I just have basic understanding of mysql. Need your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  location
,       sum(case when PercentageRaised >= 1.0 then 1 end) as successful
,       sum(case when PercentageRaised < 1.0 then 1 end) as unsuccessful
from    YourTable
group by
        location
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Supports boolean arithmetic.

```
SELECT  Location,
        SUM(percentageRaised > 0) successful,
        SUM(percentageRaised < 0) unsuccessful,
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Location
```